# ¿Cómo comparar si dos arrays son iguales o tienen los mismos valores?

Tags: javascript, array

Quería saber como comparo dos arrays para saber si estos son iguales. Por ejemplo:

```
const array1 = [1,2,3];
const array2 = [1,2,3];
const array3 = [2,3,1];
```

En el caso de `array3`, como hacer para saber si tienen los mismos valores aunque estén en otro orden.
¿Es necesario iterarlos? ¿o hay alguna forma de compararlos sin un `for`?

Comment: Una opción es ordenarlos y luego compararlos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comparar 2 `Arrays` simples (como los que muestras en la pregunta) y de la forma que deseas, debes comparar no solo que cada elemento de uno este incluido en el otro, sino que ambos tengan el mismo tamaño. Eso te garantiza que son iguales.

Por ejemplo, podrías tener una función que reciba 2 elementos de tipo `Array` y devuelva `true` si ambos son iguales y `false` en caso contrario.

Para escribir esta función, nos apoyaremos en el método [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) que itera cada elemento de un `Array`. Como los elementos de ambos `Array` pueden estar en cualquier orden y se considera que los mismos son iguales sin importar el orden, entonces nos apoyaremos también en el método [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para comparar los 2 arrays con sus elementos ordenandos.

La función puede quedar como la siguiente:

```js
function sonIguales(a, b) {
  if(!Array.isArray(a) || !Array.isArray(b)) return false;
  let sorted_a = [ ...a ].sort();
  let sorted_b = [ ...b ].sort();
  return (
    sorted_a.length === sorted_b.length &&
    sorted_a.every((element, index) => element === sorted_b[index])
  );
}

let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [1, 1, 4];
let array3 = [2, 3, 1];

console.log(sonIguales(array1, array2)); // false
console.log(sonIguales(array1, array3)); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esta sería una forma de comparar si dos `Array` son iguales, en tamaño y en elementos, sin importar el orden de los mismos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!, la finalidad de esta pregunta era porque estoy haciendo un proyecto de tic-tac-toe, y quiero comparar un array con todos las jugadas ganadoras posibles, con otro array como por ejemplo movimientosX[], que va a almacenar todos los movimientos que haga este jugador, este ultimo eventualmente va a tener mas de 3 elementos, puede tener 4 o 5, es posible compararlos aunque tenga mas elementos que el otro? Espero haber sido claro

Comment: Pues la comparación ya no sería de igualdad. Por lo tanto esto no te sirve para ese propósito, creo que deberías pensar primero el tipo de comparación que deseas y de acuerdo a eso implementar una solución. Te invito a hacer esa pregunta diferente en el sitio, mostrando lo que has intentado, el comportamiento actual y el resultado esperado. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a hacer! saludos

Answer (score 3):

La opción más fácil que yo veo es usar [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) en los dos arrays para convertirlos a un string y luego comparar los strings

Por motivos de que puede haber arrays anidados, vamos a usar [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) para obtener todo en un solo array, finalmente vamos a [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para ordernarlos

```js
function array_equal(arr1,arr2) {
  if ((Array.isArray(arr1) && Array.isArray(arr2)) === false) return false;
  return JSON.stringify([...new Set(arr1.flat().sort())]) === JSON.stringify([...new Set(arr2.flat().sort())]);
}

console.log(array_equal([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3, [4]])); // true
console.log(array_equal([1,2,3,4], [1,2,[3], [4]])); // true
console.log(array_equal([1, 3, 2], [3, 2 ,1])); // true
console.log(array_equal([1, 3, 2, [3]], [3, 2 ,1])); // true
console.log(array_equal([1, 3, 2, [4]], [3, 2 ,1])); // false
```